# How to use DecimalPipe from component in angular?

Tags: angular, pipe, angular7, angular-pipe

I have a requirement that I have to convert the number using the decimal pipe from ts

Instead of use decimal pipe like this

```
<td>{{rmanFmvRulesDef.max  | number :'1.2-2'}}</td>
```

I want to manipulate it from the component, can anyone please help me?

Answer (score 65, accepted):

As usual in angular you can rely on DI. You can override the transform function in the ts.

```js
import { DecimalPipe } from '@angular/common';

class MyService {
  constructor(private _decimalPipe: DecimalPipe) {}

  transformDecimal(num) {
    return this._decimalPipe.transform(num, '1.2-2');
  }
}
```

Add DecimalPipe in the providers Array otherwise it will give an error

```js
providers: [DecimalPipe,...]
```

Comment: Adding the pipe to providers instead of declarations was one imported missing information. Thanks for this!

Comment: The correct format is '1.2-2' for future references

Comment: **Note**: this does not behave exactly the same as regular pipe (display). Observed on angular 9. -- Regular: `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}` vs Used with input field or direct API: `{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits|maxIntegerDigits}`

Comment: @ddsultan I am having the same issue. This does not exactly behave has regular pipe display. But id did not understand if you had any solution for this. I tried giving as '1.2-2|1' but it does not work.

Comment: @Goli, I used a custom RegEx

Answer (score 6):

You can also use [formatNumber](https://angular.io/api/common/formatNumber) function (DecimalPipe uses it under the hood). No need for dealing with DI or adding anything to the providers array.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively, as you could see the example on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gcyuxx)**, you can use `accounting`.

Just simply call by: `element.price = format.formatCurrency(element.price);`

Once you've define the helper. You could define by:
`<h2 *ngFor="let item of item">{{ item.price }}</h2>` as example.

Component:

```
import { accounting } from 'accounting';

export function formatCurrency(value) {
    return accounting.formatMoney(value, '', 0, ' ', '.');
}

export function unformatCurrency(value) {
    return accounting.unformat(value);
}
```

Note: `return accounting.formatMoney(value, '', 0, ' ', '.');` You can change `' '` and `.` with whatever splitter that you want `,` or space. For how many number behind decimal you could update the `0` number to how many digits you want.

Comment: What is accounting?

Comment: https://github.com/openexchangerates/accounting.js