# adding key value to an object in typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How do we insert key and values to an existing array of object based on a condition, can this be solve using map ? in a single line ? . Thanks

If dealType from the object is === PM Restructure  insert new key and value and if dealType Partner Location Submission remove annualRentProposed and annualRentCurrent.

Thanks for any idea and help.

cashContribution : 3000,
storeCashFlow : 4000,

#data

```
  this.data.object = [
        {
            "id": 196,
            "name": "Partner Deal ",
            "dealType": "Partner Location Submission",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 197,
            "name": "Buyout Deal Disposition",
            "dealType": "Idle Buyout",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 199,
            "name": "Sublease Deal Disposition",
            "dealType": "Idle Sublease",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "09/30/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 203,
            "name": "Disposition of Location #10532-S",
            "dealType": "PM Restructure",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/01/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 214,
            "name": null,
            "dealType": "Approval to Close",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/04/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        },
        {
            "id": 215,
            "name": "pmpm",
            "dealType": "PM Restructure",
            "annualRentProposed": null,
            "annualRentCurrent": null,
            "firmTermRemaining": null,
            "firmTermAdded": null,
            "maxAvailableTerm": null,
            "capitalContribution": null,
            "createdOnString": "10/05/2021",
            "fileName": null,
            "serverFileName": null,
            "size": null,
            "absoluteUri": null,
            "sentTo": null
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `Array.map()`, using a simple .map() function.

We use a switch statement on dealType to decide how to map each deal.

By default we just leave the deal unmodified.

One could extend the logic used in 'PM Restructure' to add more parameters for other deal types too.

```js
const input = [ { "id": 196, "name": "Partner Deal ", "dealType": "Partner Location Submission", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "09/30/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null }, { "id": 197, "name": "Buyout Deal Disposition", "dealType": "Idle Buyout", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "09/30/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null }, { "id": 199, "name": "Sublease Deal Disposition", "dealType": "Idle Sublease", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "09/30/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null }, { "id": 203, "name": "Disposition of Location #10532-S", "dealType": "PM Restructure", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "10/01/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null }, { "id": 214, "name": null, "dealType": "Approval to Close", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "10/04/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null }, { "id": 215, "name": "pmpm", "dealType": "PM Restructure", "annualRentProposed": null, "annualRentCurrent": null, "firmTermRemaining": null, "firmTermAdded": null, "maxAvailableTerm": null, "capitalContribution": null, "createdOnString": "10/05/2021", "fileName": null, "serverFileName": null, "size": null, "absoluteUri": null, "sentTo": null } ]

 // Function that maps each deal according to the dealType        
function mapDeal(deal, parameters) {
    switch (deal.dealType) {

        case 'PM Restructure':
            // Add any extra parameters for PM Restructure
            return { ...deal, ...(parameters['PM Restructure'] || {})};

        case 'Partner Location Submission':
            // Remove annualRentProposed, annualRentCurrent using object destructuring
            const { annualRentProposed, annualRentCurrent, ...rest } = deal;
            return rest;
         
        default:
            // Leave the deal as it is
            return deal;
    }
}
 
function mapDeals(input, parameters) {
    return input.map(deal => mapDeal(deal, parameters));
}
 
const parameters = { 
    'PM Restructure': { 
        cashContribution: 3000,
        storeCashFlow: 4000
    }
}
 
console.log(mapDeals(input, parameters))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Sir just an additional question , how do we convert in typescript the number to an amount for example the input is 424109 , it should be 424,109 . Thanks.

Comment: not in angular template but in code

Comment: You might want to look at Intl.NumberFormat: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat. This will format numbers according to locale rules.

Comment: do we still have to consider the currency?

Comment: I dont need the currency Sir , it should only be a number and comma separated

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53810595/how-to-use-decimalpipe-from-component-in-angular

Comment: You could try something like: console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US').format(424109 )); That will give you an output of 424,109.

Comment: also what round do we use to round 11.833333 to 11.8

Comment: I'd suggest looking at Angular Pipes: https://www.ngdevelop.tech/angular/pipes/#built-in-pipes. these are very flexible and allow a lot of formatting options. You could also use: console.log(new Intl.NumberFormat('en-US', { maximumFractionDigits: 1 }).format(11.83333 )); See all options here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl/NumberFormat/NumberFormat.